# If the metric of a routing table destination is higher than another, can it connect through it, if the lower metric destination offers no connection?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing

When a host is unreachable via the route with the higher priority metric (lower value of metric), will the OS use the route with the lower priority metric without removing the high priority route from the routing table, even when the higher priority gateway is still reachable?

An example would be: routing with high priority (low metric) with an ethernet cable and low priority to a wireless hotspot and suddenly: **while high priority gateway is reachable**: it loses internet connectivity with that route.

Answer (score 2):

"Host is unreachable" is a different situation from "no internet connectivity", with different results.

The OS *may* have explicit "Internet connectivity" detection by periodically contacting a designated host (like the 'msftncsi' server in Windows), and *may* change route priorities depending on the results. For example, NetworkManager in Linux will automatically add 20000 to the metric of all default routes that don't provide "Internet access", which is determined by contacting a specific HTTP URL.

But when any other remote host is unreachable, the OS *doesn't* automatically conclude that "there's no Internet access" from that alone, and will not try any alternative routes.

One exception is if a *local* gateway itself is unreachable (doesn't answer to ARP aka neighbour discovery queries), in which case the OS may try alternative gateways for the same route on the *same* interface. This primarily happens in IPv6, where multiple routers can advertise themselves with different priorities.

Comment: Interesting. That also begs the question:  if the OS doesn't do it: how do I do it? E.g. I'm interesting in ubuntu server doing it.

Comment: Hrm , I guess networkmanager itself you mentioned may do it. I wonder if it's automatic.